# How can I convert HQL inner join to LINQ join

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, join, hql

How can I write this HQL in Linq:

```
select a from A a
join a.childrenList b
where b = 1
```

`childrenList` is a list of enums which is not mapped to database by type but
rather is saved with its integer value.

This HQL works fine but I want to write it in Linq.
I cannot write something that can be compiled.

Comment: Especially [for germans](http://www.dict.cc/german-english/Aa.html) ;)

Comment: I don't know NH or HQL but I have a weird feeling this could work: `session.Query<A>().Where(a => a.childrenList.Any(b => b.c == 1));`

Comment: if b is an enum, what is b.c ? You should post your concrete classes/types, with what is mapped and not

Comment: @w0lf: Thanks. Your suggestion works. I wrote my query as follows. `from A a in db.Query<A>() where a.childrenList.Any(b => b == (B) 1) select a`

Comment: @jbl: I made a mistake. I wanted to ask my question in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do

```
var results = 
    from a in db.Query<A>() 
    where a.childrenList.Any(b => b == (B)1)
    select a;
```

or, using chained methods:

```
var results = db.Query<A>().Where(a => a.childrenList.Any(b => b == (B)1));
```

Regarding our comments above, I think you can drop the `from A a in ... select a` statements, because they are redundant.

Comment: `from A a` is needed since the `a` in `a.childrenList` is bound to it. This Linq query works but it is converted to a `where exists...` query rather than a `join` query.

Comment: @S.M.Amin yes, sorry, I didn't pay enough attention when writing that version. What I meant was that `from/select` would not be needed if using chained LINQ methods. I've updated my answer.